# Quarter page numbering

Tags: numbering, page-numbering

In documents by the German parliament there are quarter page numbers (e.g. page 9686 D for the fourth quarter of page 9686, [(example)](http://dipbt.bundestag.de/doc/btp/18/18101.pdf)). How do I create such numbering in LaTeX including these numbering in the toc?

Comment: But A,B,C,D are not related to the page number. The page numbering are sequential. The letters are used in the text body.

Comment: @sigur but in the TOC these are used as a page number.

Comment: The 'page' numbers are always there, so they can be placed with something like `everyshi`. The connection between the content and the 'page' number is more tricky. I think, `zref` could be of use here

Answer (score 7):

This is very interesting problem. So I tried to solve this in my favorite macro package, i.e. plain TeX. You can be inspired by this and you (or somebody else) can try to re-implement these ideas to LaTeX.

We need to set the `\output` routine in order to do the specified page design. I din't do this (for sake of simplicity and for the reason that plain TeX isn't the desired macro package). I only set one page "manually" using defined `\dopage` macro for experiments. But the main principles are shown here.

```
\input opmac

\def\lorem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
  adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
  adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
  libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec 
  vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique   
  senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut
  leo.}

\splittopskip=12pt  
\long\def\dopage#1{%
   \setbox0=\vbox{\hsize=7cm \emergencystretch=2em \penalty0
                  #1\par\nobreak\vfil\penalty0}
   \setbox1=\vsplit0 to0pt
   \hbox{\vbox to240pt{\hbox{(A)}\vfil\hbox{(B)}\vfil}\kern5pt
      \vbox{\setpartpage{A}%
            \setbox1=\vsplit0 to 120pt
            \edef\tmp{\the\dp1}\box1 \kern-\tmp
            \setpartpage{B}%  
            \vsplit0 to120pt}%
      \kern5pt\vrule\kern5pt
      \vbox{\setpartpage{C}%
            \setbox1=\vsplit0 to 120pt
            \edef\tmp{\the\dp1}\box1 \kern-\tmp
            \setpartpage{D}%  
            \vsplit0 to120pt}%
    \kern5pt\vbox to240pt{\hbox{(C)}\vfil\hbox{(D)}\vfil}}
}
\def\setpartpage#1{\wref\addto{\noexpand\toclist{\def\noexpand\partpage{#1}}}}
\def\pglink#1{#1 \partpage}

\maketoc 
\vskip1cm

\dopage{
  \sec First item

  \lorem

  \sec Second item

  \lorem \par \lorem

  \sec Third item 

  \lorem
}
\bye
```

The result is:

[image: quarter page]

Explanation: We need to `\vsplit` the page contents to four parts, first two will be the first column and second two to the second column. Then we need to `\write` to the REF file (or AUX or TOC file if LaTeX is used) the information about the part of the page before each part. This is done by `\setpartpage` macro. For example, we have the following contents in the REF file using OPmac:

```
 %% OPmac - REF file
\Xpage{1}
\addto\toclist {\def \partpage {A}}
\Xtoc{1}{\rm }{1}{First item }{1}
\addto\toclist {\def \partpage {B}}
\Xtoc{1}{\rm }{2}{Second item }{1}
\addto\toclist {\def \partpage {C}}
\addto\toclist {\def \partpage {D}}
\Xtoc{1}{\rm }{3}{Third item }{1}
```

This means that `\toclist` will include after REF file is read:

```
\def\partpage {A}
\tocline{1}{\rm}{1}{First item }{1} % {level}{font}{sec number}{text}{page}
\def\partpage {B}
\tocline{1}{\rm}{2}{Second item }{1}
\def\partpage {C}
\def\partpage {D}
\tocline{1}{\rm}{3}{Third item }{1}
```

Now, we need only re-define `\tocline` in order to it prints not only 
`#5` (the pageno) but the `\partpage` too. I did this by redefinig
`\pglink` which is used in tocline for printing page number. This isn't very conceptional because the `\hyperlinks` are broken here but we use this only as an experimental code.